# can't change the value of the variable in snackBar

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-snackbar, snackbar

the variable should get value false at hint 1
but when it checked in the if statement at hint 2 is still true
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIXGn.png)

Comment: don't expect us to visit external links, post all relevant information in your question

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 1):

That's because set action and onClickListener is a nonsynchronous callback.

The code that actually sets the boolean value to false doesn't execute immediately. So when you get to the if statement the value still hasn't changed.

Comment: what can I do to solve this problem

Comment: Add a function call inside the listener's code that does the needed adjustments.